# passing json array form in the put storage method in laravel php

Tags: php, json, laravel, storage

iam trying to pass $data array to save it in the laravel storage files
my code is :

```
$data = '[
            {
                "label": " Total Accidents",
                "color": "#5ab1ef",
                "data": 
                    [
                        ["Jan",0],
                        ["Feb",0],
                        ["Mar",0],
                        ["Apr",0],
                        ["May",0],
                        ["Jun",0],
                        ["Jul",0],
                        ["Aug",0],
                        ["Sep",0]
                    ]
            },
            {
                "label": " Active Experts",
                "color": "#f5994e",
                "data": 
                    [
                        ["Jan",0],
                        ["Feb",0],
                        ["Mar",0],
                        ["Apr",0],
                        ["May",0],
                        ["Jun",0],
                        ["Jul",0],
                        ["Aug",0],
                        ["Sep",0]
                    ]
            },
            {
                "label": " Pending Payments",
                "color": "#d87a80",
                "data": 
                    [
                        ["Jan",0],
                        ["Feb",0],
                        ["Mar",0],
                        ["Apr",0],
                        ["May",0],
                        ["Jun",0],
                        ["Jul",0],
                        ["Aug",0],
                        ["Sep",0]
                    ]
            }

      ]';   
 $test = json_decode($data, true);
 $test[0]['data'][1] =  ["Jan", 153];
 Storage::disk('chartData')
    ->put('chart/test'.$_SESSION['companyId'].'.json', $test);
 return 'done';
```

i want to change the values inside each year according to database values , the problem is that when iam trying to put method iam getting the following error :

> Array to string conversion

if i pass $data array without doing json_decode it works fine , but in this case i cant change the data isnide the array , so i have to decode it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should use `json_encode` function to convert your JSON data to string.

```
$test[0]['data'][1] =  ["Jan", 153];

$test = json_encode($test);// convert to string

Storage::disk('chartData')
->put('chart/test'.$_SESSION['companyId'].'.json', $test);
```